# Angular 2 RC2 New Forms

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

As suggested in article:

https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/1RIezQqE4aEhBRmArIAS1mRIZtWFf6JxN_7B4meyWK0Y/pub

that in order to use new forms in RC2 we need to disable deprecated forms using below code:

```
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
   disableDeprecatedForms(),
   provideForms()
])
```

Which apparently means that we now also need to include below in our package.json:

```
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.2",
```

But when I add "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.2", to my package.json and try to restore packages it gives below errors:

```
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3
npm ERR! No compatible version found: @angular/forms@2.0.0-rc.2
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! 0.1.0
```

Can anyone please guide?

Comment: why don't you use `@angular/forms-deprecated` itself..?

Comment: Want to explore new forms in RC2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found that in order to use new forms introduced in Angular 2 RC2, we need to add below package to our packages.json file:

```
"@angular/forms": "0.1.0"
```

You may also find below answer useful:

[How to migrate Angular 2 RC 1 (or earlier) Forms to Angular 2 RC 2 / RC 4 New Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871271/how-to-migrate-angular-2-rc-1-or-earlier-forms-to-angular-2-rc-2-new-forms/37902014#37902014)