# How to migrate Angular 2 RC 1 (or earlier) Forms to Angular 2 RC 2 / RC 4 New Forms

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

I need to migrate my existing Angular 2 RC 1 app to Angular 2 RC 4. As a part of which I also need to move my existing forms to Angular 2 RC 4 New Forms.

Can anyone please guide, how to update existing forms to new form.

Comment: What's the problem with validators? Can you reproduce in a Plunker? You can use https://plnkr.co/edit/ir19tuktTqcfGeG8pu2G?p=preview as template.

Comment: Custom validators requires key in result to be this same as validator name when incorrect, so the result will be return { "numeric": true }; Besides for this purpose you do not need custom validator as there is Pattern as one of the standard validators from RC1.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For those who are having trouble in migrating forms from Angular 2 RC 1 (or earlier) to Angular 2 RC 2 / RC 4 New Forms. Here are the steps they need to follow:

Include new forms in your project by adding below package to their packages.json:

```
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
```

Next, they have to disable the deprecated forms in main file and include new forms something like below:

```
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
   disableDeprecatedForms(),
   provideForms()
])
```

Then in their component add import for new form directives:

```
import { REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

Include REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES for the component:

```
directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
```

In your component rename the following:

```
ControlGroup > FormGroup
Control > FormControl
```

In your templates rename the following:

```
ngFormModel > formGroup
ngControl > formControlName
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: There are more important changes here... Please refer to: https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/1RIezQqE4aEhBRmArIAS1mRIZtWFf6JxN_7B4meyWK0Y/pub

Comment: Thank you Baumi, you are right, even I actually followed that post :)