# Using Angular 2 Material 2 Alpha 5 with Angular 2 RC 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-material2

A few days back I started exploring the recently released Angular 2 RC 2 and tried to migrate my app from Angular 2 RC 1 to Angular 1 RC 2.

I am using Angular 2 Material 2 Alpha 5 in my app.

Though the migration didn't take much time, when I compiled and ran the app, I found the forms using Angular 2 material 2 components were broken.

The material form controls don't work with Angular 2 RC 2, and the console shows the following errors:

```
EXCEPTION: No value accessor for 'firstName'.
```

I tested it on `md-input`, `md-slide-toggle` and `md-checkbox` and I receive below exception on all of them.

```
EXCEPTION: No value accessor for 'Field name'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have successfully migrated your forms to Angular 2 RC 2.

If you are migrating your Angular 2 RC 1 (or earlier) forms to Angular 2 RC 2
you might find this helpful for new forms

[How to migrate Angular 2 RC 1 (or earlier) Forms to Angular 2 RC 2 / RC 4 New Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871271/how-to-migrate-angular-2-rc-1-or-earlier-forms-to-angular-2-rc-2-new-forms/37902014#37902014)

For angular material to work you need to make below changes:

**Replace**

```
var common_1 = require('@angular/common');
```

**with**

```
var common_1 = require('@angular/forms');
```

in the following files:

```
node_modules/@angular2-material/checkbox/checkbox.js
node_modules/@angular2-material/input/input.js
node_modules/@angular2-material/radio/radio.js
node_modules/@angular2-material/slide-toggle/slide-toggle.js
```

Though making above changes in material components source files works for other components but doesn't to work for Checkboxes. This change does remove the ValueAccessor error on form load, but when the form is submitted it posts below object in case of checkbox if its checked:

```
myCheckbox: MdCheckboxChange
checked:true
source:MdCheckbox
__proto__:Object
constructor:MdCheckboxChange()
__proto__:Object
```

In order to fix this, we need to make another change in the following file:

```
node_modules/@angular2-material/checkbox/checkbox.js
```

**Locate**

```
MdCheckbox.prototype.registerOnChange = function (fn) {
    if (this._changeSubscription) {
        this._changeSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    this._changeSubscription = this.change.subscribe(fn);
};
```

**and replace it with the following**:

```
MdCheckbox.prototype.registerOnChange = function (fn) {
        if (this._changeSubscription) {
            this._changeSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        this._changeSubscription = this.change
        .map(function (v) {
            return v.checked;
        })
        .subscribe(fn);
    };
```

I hope you will find the above useful.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to add "provideForms" call to your bootstrap code in main.ts (or js)

My bootstrap code looks like

```js
return bootstrap(<Type>AppComponent, [
    ...PROVIDERS,
    ...ENV_PROVIDERS,
    ...DIRECTIVES,
    ...PIPES,
    ...APP_PROVIDERS,
    ...APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms()
])
```