# Angular2 old forms module warning

Tags: angular

I have created simple Angular2 application as mentioned in quick-start guide and then added couple of routes for navigation purpose.

In each of the components, i am displaying simple H1 tag indicating component1 and component2. This is to verify navigation happening correctly. My application works fine without any error. But I do receive one warning message in browser's chrome. I want to understand how to resolve this warning?

**PLEASE NOTE: I am not using anything from `@angular2/common` or `@angular/forms` modules.**

[old forms module warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w82QI.png)

My environment is-

Angular2 version: 2.0.0-rc.4

npm version:  3.9.6

node version: 4.4.7

Browser: chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these providers to `bootstrap`:

```
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
   disableDeprecatedForms(),
   provideForms()
])
```

and don't import any forms stuff from `@angular/common`. Only import these from `@angular/forms`.

See also [Angular 2 RC2 New Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864577/angular-2-rc2-new-forms)

Comment: please put comma after disableDeprecatedForms()